# How to delete duplicate row in mysql table based on the value of a third column in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP. I am asking for help to delete a row according to the value of the third column. My table consist of ID and DateTime fields. Here is the code that I tried but I am stuck to what to do next:

```
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname)
    or die("Couldn't connect to server");
$qry = "select ID, DATE(ValidDateTime) as Date, TIME(ValidDateTime) as Time from tempstore order by ID";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$qry) or die("Couldn't execute query");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    extract($row);
    $Hours = date("H",strtotime($Time));
    if ($ID[$i] == $ID[$i+1]) {
        echo "<p>$ID $Date $Hours</p>\n";
    }
    $i++;
    //print_r($Hours);
}
```

I extract the date and time from DateTime fields in my table then extract again the hours from Time to distinguish if the user have inputs in the same hour in the same date and delete it leaving only his/her first inputs in different hours. I hope you can understand what I am trying to achieve and help me solve this problem. Thank you in advance.